# $http.POST not working with DATETIME datatype (AngularJS, Spring 4.2, MySQL, Hibernate)

Tags: mysql, angularjs, spring, hibernate, http

Trying to insert a new record in my table and I always get an error 400 (bad request, syntax error) when I want to insert a row with a date field. I tested the POST having removed the "date" field from the form and it works. It stops working as soon as I add this input. It is a simple text input and I'm using the date (copy/paste) from an existing row to test it because it works with the $http.PUT.

I have the 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

When I update an existing row ($http.PUT) it works perfectly, but when I try to create a new one it doesn't. I'm new to all of this and I searched many forums but I can't find any example doing what I want to do.

I don't know what to provide to help you understanding but ask me and I will share.

Thank you very much! Your help is very appreciated!

EDIT: I'm adding Angular code to help

```
$scope.createDepense = function (newDepenseForm) {

    if (!newDepenseForm.$valid) {
        $scope.displayValidationError = true;
        return;
    }

    $scope.lastAction = 'create';

    var url = $scope.url;

    var config = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}};

    $scope.addSearchParametersIfNeeded(config, false);

    $scope.startDialogAjaxRequest();
    debugger;

    $http.post(url, $.param($scope.depense), config)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.finishAjaxCallOnSuccess(data, "#addDepensesModal", false);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(config);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
            debugger;
            $scope.handleErrorInDialogs(status);
        });
};
```

And my model:

```
        import java.sql.Timestamp;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;


    @Entity
    public class Depenses {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id_fact")
        private int idFact;

        @Column(name="date_eff")
        private Timestamp dateEff;

etc...
```

And this is when I update a record (PUT, working)
[working $http.PUT with date changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq7tU.png)

And $http.POST not working
[not working $http.POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k45rT.png)

Also tried this but no success

```
    @Column(name="date_eff")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateEff;
```

Comment: Are you sending the data as a string? as a Date? In the backend what kind of type is the server expecting? If your POSTs work in different contexts it is likely to be a data format issue.

Comment: yes it seems to be related to data format. the database field is a "datetime". As I can see when debugging Angular, in the $scope the data, when POSTing, is String (between double quotes).

Comment: thx a lot, your questions sent me on the "format" path! it helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AND FINALLY I FOUND!

Changed model:

```
@Column(name="date_eff", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateEff;
```

And this in the .jsp input type="text" for:

```
<input type="date"
    autofocus
    ng-model="depense.dateEff"
    name="dateEff"
/>
```

And Voila! fixed!